# Accessing the in-place editor with the keyboard

Tags: nodes, navigation

Can a administrator user open the in-place editor using the keyboard?

Editing multiple nodes would be less annoying than it is now.

Comment: If you are editing dozens or hundreds of nodes a day, I'd recommend looking into editable fields, editable tables and doing like twenty or fifty at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my module, **[Instant Transmission](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/no-sssweat/2775899)**.

> Why waste time moving the mouse cursor 7000 pixels or navigating drop
>   downs or scrolling down the page to hit the save button, when you can
>   use ... Instant Transmission.
>
> Instant Transmission allows you to quickly edit or configure nodes/blocks
>   much faster than ever before.